# Rdlc excel report without sheet

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

Rdlc excel report showing with sheets when I set page break group for page size.How to get all data row with one page(one sheet) without spreading sheets.

Comment: I need to use page break

Comment: I also generate pdf,  it is working. But not in excel

Comment: I didn't go into details, but maybe this would help: http://www.44342.com/ASP-NET-f54-t524-p1.htm